# React changing text of element by looping through array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iteration, setinterval

I have an array of text items that looks like this

```
const sentences  = ['sentence one', 'sentence two', 'sentence three', 'sentence four']
```

I am trying to make the elements text loop through each sentence displaying each one for five seconds, with a typing effect outwards, then a backspace effect then it types out the next sentence and loops.

The code I have will type out the first sentence, backspace, type out the second sentence and then it will backspace and type out the second sentence again over and over... Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

This is the code I have

```
  const sentences = ['sentence one', 'sentence two', 'sentence three', 'sentence four']
  const [sentence, setSentence] = useState(sentences[0])
  let index = 0
  if(index < 3) {
    setInterval(() => {
      index++
      setSentence(sentences[index])
    }, 5000)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time your component mounts, your `index` variable gets set to 0 again. `index` variable should be stored in state:

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
```

You need to set your interval inside the `useEffect` to prevent infinite remounting. Then in your `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setIndex(index + 1)
    }, 5000)

  return (() => clearInterval(interval)) //This is a cleanup function
})
```

Finally, you can render your sentence like `sentences[index]` without the need of a `sentence` state variable. You can take a look at the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-wood-82bst?file=/src/App.js) I created for this question

Comment: I got this working thank you for the help. Do you mind explaining  what the clean up function does?

Comment: Glad it helped, please accept the answer if it answered your question :) Sure, cleanup function basically interrupts the ongoing function when your component unmounts. There are far better resources than me to explain this. Check out [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) or this helpful tutorial (where I learned) [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKOQtGLT-Yk&ab_channel=TheNetNinja)

Comment: I kinda just tried it with and without the clean up function and realised that without sometimes after a few iterations, the text would be displaying more than one item from the array but flashing between them. 

After adding the clean up function this no longer happens. 

Thanks for the links I'll take a look

Comment: I wouldn't expect that behavior. Maybe that happens when your component unmounts and remounts when the index is getting updated. Since setInterval is asynchronous, that unexpected behavior may happen. Just guessing though

Comment: Any advice on stopping that unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

this would be something which you need, I just edited the above codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-goodall-ypntd

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const loopArr = [
  "sentence1",
  "sentence2",
  "sentence3",
  "sentence4",
  "sentence5",
  "sentence5 sentence5"
];

export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalDelayMilliseconds = loopArr[index].length * 500;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setIndex((prevIndex) => {
        // reset index if current index is greater than array size
        return prevIndex + 1 < loopArr.length ? prevIndex + 1 : 0;
      });
    }, intervalDelayMilliseconds);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div class="typewriter">
        <h1 key={loopArr[index]}>{loopArr[index]}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, 

I attempted to try it out this way but just ended up with it repeating the first sentence over and over

Comment: can you share the code?
and see the output of the above sandbox here https://ypntd.csb.app/